# Help with Mathematica Plot

Tags: plotting

I'm attempting to recreate a Penrose Diagram in Mathematica from this paper:

https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/6bee/5e712cb09fdc97d38a361c9bff3e4beb0125.pdf

Pg: 12,13.

I'm not very familiar with Mathematica, but I feel like there will be a silly error somewhere in the code, although none show when I run it.

```
Clear[x, y, x1, y1, ep, ep, m]; m = 1; rmax = 10;
ep[rmin, tmin] := Sqrt[Abs[1 - r/2 m]]*E^((r + t)/4 m);
ep[rmin, tmin] := Sqrt[Abs[1 - r/2 m]]*E^((r - t)/4 m);
x[rmin, tmin] := ArcTan[ep[r, t]] + ArcTan[-en[r, t]] /; r <= 2 m
x[rmin, tmin] := 0 /; r > 2 m
y[rmin, tmin] := ArcTan[ep[r, t]] - ArcTan[-en[r, t]] /; r <= 2 m
y[rmin, tmin] := 0 /; r > 2 m
x1[rmin, tmin] := 
 ArcTan[ep[r, t]] + ArcTan[-en[r, t]] /; r \[GreaterSlantEqual] 2 m
x1[rmin, tmin] := 0 /; r < 2 m
y1[rmin, tmin] := 
 ArcTan[ep[r, t]] - ArcTan[-en[r, t]] /; r \[GreaterSlantEqual] 2 m
y1[rmin, tmin] := 0 /; r < 2 m
maps1234 := 
  ParametricPlot3D[{{x[r, t], y[r, t], 0}, {-x[r, t], -y[r, t], 
     0}, {x1[r, t], y1[r, t], 0}, {-x1[r, t] - y1[r, t], 0}}, {r, 0, 
    rmax}, {t, -10, 10}, ViewPoint -> {0, 0, -3.38}, Boxed -> False, 
   Axes -> False];
Show[Graphics[{Arrow[{{0.5, 0.5}, {0.5, 0.85}}], 
    Arrow[{{0.5, 0.5}, {1.1, 0.5}}], Text["x", {1.1, 0.45}], 
    Text["y", {0.45, 0.85}], 
    Text["\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(\[Tau]\), \(-\)]\)", {0.9, 0.4}], 
    Text["\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(\[Tau]\), \(+\)]\)", {0.9, 0.6}], 
    Text["\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(I\), \(0\)]\)", {0.96, 0.45}], 
    Text["\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(I\), \(+\)]\)", {0.75, 0.75}], 
    Text["\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(I\), \(-\)]\)", {0.75, 0.25}], 
    Text["r=0", {0.4, 0.75}], Text["r=0", {0.4, 0.25}]}], 
  WireFrame[maps1234]];
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The 2nd and 3rd lines differ by a minus sign, which is expected given the nature of the coordinates. My hope was to follow the code of this paper and produce a plot and try and apply it to my coordinates - whilst learning some of the basics in the process. The rmin etc were just cause at the time I wasn't sure how to add subscripts.

Comment: Look carefully in the paper and you will see the mistakes. When defining functions you are missing the underscore (`ep[r_,t_]`). Also, it is `Abs[1 - r/(2 m)]` not `Abs[1 - r/2 m]`. Correct all of them and see what you get. If you simply copy paste from a text file it may not appear correctly. You have to write them by hand.

Answer (score 6):

I can rewrite your code to get rid of a lot of your misunderstanding of Mathematica semantics, and I hope my work will help you move forward. Unfortunately, it is not clear from your mixture of 2D and 3D graphics which space you really need to work in. I have reduced the code to be consistently 2D.

```
m = 1; rmax = 10;

ep[r_, t_] := Sqrt[Abs[1 - r/2 m]] E^((r + t)/4 m);
en[r_, t_] := Sqrt[Abs[1 - r/2 m]] E^((r - t)/4 m);
x[r_, t_] := ArcTan[ep[r, t]] + ArcTan[-en[r, t]] /; r <= 2 m
x[r_, t_] := 0 /; r > 2 m
y[r_, t_] := ArcTan[ep[r, t]] - ArcTan[-en[r, t]] /; r <= 2 m
y[r_, t_] := 0 /; r > 2 m
x1[r_, t_] := ArcTan[ep[r, t]] + ArcTan[-en[r, t]] /; r >= 2 m
x1[r_, t_] := 0 /; r < 2 m
y1[r_, t_] := ArcTan[ep[r, t]] - ArcTan[-en[r, t]] /; r >= 2 m
y1[r_, t_] := 0 /; r < 2 m

maps1234 =
  ParametricPlot[
   {{x[r, t], y[r, t]}, {-x[r, t], -y[r, t]}, {x1[r, t], y1[r, t]}, {-x1[r, t] - y1[r, t]}},
   {r, 0, rmax}, {t, -30, 30}];

labeling =
  Graphics[
    {Arrow[{{0.5, 0.5}, {0.5, 0.85}}],
     Arrow[{{0.5, 0.5}, {1.1, 0.5}}],
     Text["x", {1.1, 0.45}],
     Text["y", {0.45, 0.85}],
     Text[SuperMinus[\[Tau]], {0.9, 0.4}],
     Text[SuperPlus[\[Tau]], {0.9, 0.6}],
     Text[Superscript["I", 0], {0.75, 0.45}],
     Text[SuperMinus["I"], {0.75, 0.75}],
     Text[SuperPlus["I"], {0.75, 0.25}],
     Text["r = 0", {0.4, 0.75}],
     Text["r = 0", {0.4, 0.25}]}];

Show[maps1234, labeling, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: plot]

#### Notes

1. Your main problem seem to be misconceptions about how function definitions are made in Mathematica.
2. There is an inconsistency between the coordinate specifications of the labeling and the coordinate system of the plot. You need to work on that.